# Is it possible to convert java views to xml layout?

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I a created a `linearlyaout` and added views to it using `java` code. is it possible to convert this layout to `xml` layout and save it to the storage ?

Comment: you can not this. perhaps you will never need to do so, becasue all the the information u hv at compile time can be stored in xml,.modification through java doc is for rumtime alone, which can never be considered as static ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from parsing all those `Views` attributes and then building a xml layout file. However you will not be able to use that constructed xml layout(like `setContentView(R.layout.built_layout)`) like other layouts from the `res/layout` folder.